# Linux, C: threads synch

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

My application has multiple threads created by pthread_create.
Now, all other threads need to wait until a particular thread change a state, for example: one status thread is monitoring system status, if it is ready, then tell other threads to start doing their work.
How do I implement this in Linux with C?

===sudo code===

```
static int status = 0;
static pthread_mutex_t status_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void good_to_go( void )
{
        pthread_mutex_lock( &status_mutex );
        status = 1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &status_mutex );
}


void stop_doingg( void )
{
        pthread_mutex_lock( &status_mutex );
        status = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &status_mutex );
}

int is_good_to_go( void )
{
        int temp;

        pthread_mutex_lock( &status_mutex );
        temp = status;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &status_mutex );

        return temp;
}
```

then:

```
void *run_thread(void *ptr)
{
    if (is_monitor_thread)
    {
        while (check_system_status() < 0)
        {
            sleep (1);
        }
        good_to_go();
    }
    else
    {
//below while loop looks ugly. 
//is there a way to get notified once "status" is changed to 1?
        while( !is_light_turned_on() )
        {
            sleep (1);   
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for condition variables.

See the following man pages:

```
pthread_cond_init()
pthread_cond_signal()
pthread_cond_broadcast()
```

Comment: Just a small addition to the above answer - if you do use conditional variables, read the doc carefully. A lot of people consider them to be signals (which they are not!) and use them incorrectly.